# How to have control of the `Save` button while configuring new tab in MS teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-todo

I have to build a tab in MS Teams and I am looking for how I can have control of the button seen below:

[image]

By control I mean how can disable and enable accordingly.

The way Microsoft **Task By Planner and To-Do** have

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable and disable the save button by changing the setValidityState proprty of microsoftTeams.settings

For eg `microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(false);` will disable the save button and passing true value will enable it.

Thanks